# PhotoLibrary/camera is only displayed in half part of the screen,some button can't be touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I met this problem when I run my game on iPhone 4s, on the iPhone 6 and the simulators are okay. Since only part of the photo Library and camera displayed, I can't do the photo editing or press the confirm and cancel button. After this problem happened, I can't stop my game in normally. If you have met this problem or know how to solve this problem, pls do me a favor, this really trouble me for a long time, thanks.

Comment: How do you present it? presentViewController? Do you wrap it with navigation controller?

Comment: I just present it in viewController, without navigation Controller. Pls see the code below:

Comment: `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;`

    `if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;

        picker.allowsEditing = YES;

        picker.sourceType = sourceType;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"No camera");
    }`

Comment: Should I wrap it with the navigation controller?

Comment: No, it already subleasing navigation controller. 
Change the presetnModalViewController to presentViewController method. presetnModalViewController is deprecated. Maybe this is your problem. 
After that, check again..

Comment: thanks for your answer, I noticed this at your first response and changed the presentModalViewController to presentViewController, but the problem is still existing. In my this view controller, the UIActionSheet for option selected is popup in normal, and the photo Library and camera can be got.It's strange that the photo Library and camera are popup from the upside, not from the downside.

Comment: How can I control the popup Orientation of the camera and photo library? Should I rewrite the the root code for the UIImagePickerController?